# Display sparse multi-index of dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is this a bug for display sparse multi-index in Pandas.

(Running with iPython 6.2.1, Python 3.6.4)

```
In [1]: 
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

data = """
code\tname\ttyp\tntf\n
A5411\tWD\tAF\t\n
A5411\tWD\tAF\t210194618\n
B5498\tSH\tNC\t\n
B5498\tSH\tNC\t210213014\n
"""
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data))

In [2]: df.set_index(['name','code'])
Out[2]:
           typ          ntf
name code
WD   A5411  AF          NaN
     A5411  AF  210194618.0
SH   B5498  NC          NaN
     B5498  NC  210213014.0
```

I am expecting the Out[2] should be something like Out[3]

```
In [3]: df.set_index(['name', 'code', 'typ'])
Out[3]:
                        ntf
name code  typ
WD   A5411 AF           NaN
           AF   210194618.0
SH   B5498 NC           NaN
           NC   210213014.0
```

Any idea on this?